# How do I get the latest set ID in a MySQL DB table without sacrificing integrity?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, data-integrity

I'm using PHP to insert groups of records into a MySQL DB.
Whenever I insert a group of records, I want to give that group a unique set ID that is incremented by 1 for each group of records in the DB.

Currently, I'm checking the latest set ID in the DB and incrementing it by 1 for each new set of records.
The thing that scares me though is what happens if I query the DB to get the latest set ID, and before I can insert a new set of records with that set ID + 1, another insert occurs on the table thus taking the set ID I was about to use?
While fairly unlikely, something like that could greatly sacrifice the integrity of the data.

What can I do to prevent such a thing from happening? Is there any way to temporarily lock the DB table so that no other inserts can occur until I have performed a SELECT/INSERT combo?

Comment: what about using a table (with autoincrement) to get this setID by an insert into this table. The cost would be this INSERT operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locking the table is one option, but that approach impacts concurrency.

The approach I would recommend is that you use a separate table with AUTO_INCREMENT column, and use a separate INSERT into that table, and a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the auto_increment value.

And then use that value as the group identifier for the group of rows you insert into your original table.

Comment: Your recommended approach seems the most logical.  If the rows are grouped together logically, then that suggests another entity for the data model.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I concur; it's often the case that this would be an entity, but it's also possible that this "grouping" isn't. With Oracle, we could just create a `SEQUENCE` object and be done with it. My recommendation was more along the lines of emulating an Oracle SEQUENCE using a separate MySQL table.

Comment: This is an awesome idea, and one that I never thought of. Thank you. I love the simplicity of this idea, and also how easily it can be expanded out. For example, you could have a sets table that keeps track of all sets in the system by specifying a type along with the incrementing ID, etc. Obviously, an auto-incrementing ID is ideal, but it's not hard to expand this out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HartleySan: but there is the small issue of maintaining integrity between the new "sequence" table and the original table. It wouldn't be necessary to keep all the rows in the table, you could remove the rows that had the lowest values of the AUTO_INCREMENT column, and keep just the row with the "highest" value. (This is the approach I've successfully used to emulate an Oracle `SEQUENCE` object in MySQL.)

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach is:

```
LOCK TABLE foo WRITE;
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM foo
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Locking the table prevents any other process from changing the table until you explicitly unlock it.

Having said that, seriously consider just using a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. MySQL will do the work of maintaining unique keys wholly automatically, and then you can simply refer to those keys from your existing table.

Comment: Any risks associated with this approach? For example, the script halting due to an error and never getting around to unlocking the table?

Comment: The server will implicitly release all locks your session holds as soon as it disconnects. (You don't want to rely on that routinely — always call `UNLOCK TABLES` when you're done — but if something goes wrong you're not going to end up with a permanently locked table.)

Comment: LOCK locks the whole table from reading and writing. If you need to use the table to load for example an informative table in another session it is impossible because the table is locked. Why you don't manage this in your code? I assume this ID is primary key so you can check if your query is succesful or not. If it is not you can start the procedure over again. What's wrong with that?

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was asking for, but after reading spencer7593's answer, I actually think I'll go with his. Nevertheless, this is a great answer and good to know. Thank you.